# Custom function per-instance of a class (C++)

Tags: c++, function, scripting

I have a class "EngineObject"

I would like to have a custom function for that class which may vary by instance of that object.

Right now i'm doing it with function pointers like this:

```
class EngineObject{
    public:
    bool (*Update)(EngineObject* Me);
    bool (*Prep)(EngineObject* Me);
    bool (*OnCollide)(EngineObject* Me, EngineObject* Them);
};
```

As you may have noticed, this requires me to do something quite atrocious. I have to feed the object to its member function... Digusting

it also requires me to write extra getters and setters that I really don't want to be accessible from any other part of the code, just so I can see the "innards" of the EngineObject from functions passed in via function pointer

Is there some way I could write a function that I could apply, per instance of the object, that could access the privates of the object, and without having to pass the object to the function?

FOR CLARITY:
Let's say I want two EngineObjects

```
EngineObject1 = new EngineObject();
EngineObject2 = new EngineObject();
```

I'd like to set the update function of 1 to (something) and 2 to (something else)

```
EngineObject1.Update = &foo;
EngineObject2.Update = &bar;
```

I cannot simply use virtual functions and inheritance because these functions need to be able to be assigned and re-assigned at run-time.

The problem is that I need access to privates from these functions, and in order to do that i'd need to write public getters and setters for everything, which sort of erases the need for making anything private...

context:

The reason i'm doing this is to allow dynamic type generation at run time without introspection, to maximize what can be done from a scripting interface, and reduce the total number of functions that need to be bound to the scripting interface and reduce the learning curve for users.

Basically, you'd have an EngineObjectTemplate class which specified what all these functions would be for this dynamically generated type, and then the EngineObject would be created using a function in the EngineObjectTemplate class

EngineObjectTemplates may be generated at run time by combining various pre-written C++ functions (Update, Prep, OnCollide). This would be a "type" of sorts.

If a user wishes to write a new update, prep, or oncollide function, they could choose to write and compile it into a DLL file and add it to the project (Which my EXE will read and add to a list of function pointers, which can be referenced by string names in the scripting language to assign to templates and/or therefore engineobjects), or they could script it in the scripting language I choose, which would of course be slower.

Another reason why i'm doing it this way is that i'd like to avoid inheritance because it is HELL to make inherited classes work with the scripting wrapper I plan on using.

Comment: It was very hard to find the question in your text. You should edit it to make the actual question more obvious.

Comment: did you consider using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)? I.e. `std::function<bool(EngineObject* const Me)> Update;`. And how about setting the function pointer in the constructor? E.g. `EngineObject1 = new EngineObject(&foo);`

Comment: `private` is meant to block access to any code that is not part of the class, or explicitly brought it by `friend`. An externally written callback necessarily qualifies as "external" code, and allowing that to access private members would break encapsulation in a much worse way than adding accessors.

Comment: some background is good, but i would suggest to make a short example of code you have and code you would like to write

Comment: By the way, this concept sounds very unsafe. It's like an open door for hackers..

Comment: Member function pointers might help solve the pointer-to-self issue, but I'm afraid accessing privates from functions not declared inside the class won't be possible.

Comment: There are ways to do what you want cleanly, but your extra constraints make it difficult, possibly impossible, in a language like C++.

Comment: The scripting language is meant to be as powerful as possible while also being easy to use. of course it will be "susceptible to hackers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible because what you are actually asking is essentially:

"How can I make code living outside of a class access private members".

If this was possible without jumping through some ugly, ugly hoops, then it would mean that `private` is broken.

The only way to access private members of a class is that the class explicitly gives you access to them, either from its interface, or by marking the code as `friend` as part of its declaration.

Either the members are private, or they are not. You can't have it both ways.

N.B. This is a *bit* of a lie, as you can do some tricks in some exceptional corner-cases, but these should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: Well it's likely uglier than what i'm doing now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a callable object class that overrides the `()` `operator`. A base class would provide the template for what the replaceable function receives as parameters with child classes implementing that particular method. Then you declare the callable class as a `friend` to your owning class. Like the following:

```
class EngineObject;
class Callable;

class EngineObject
{
private:
  int member;
  Callable *func;

public:
  EngineObject(int m, Callable *f) : member(m), func(f) {}

  int Call(int p)
  {
    return func(p);
  }

  friend Callable;
};

class Callable;
{
public:
  int operator(EngineObject *eo, int param)
  {
    eo->member = param;
    return param;
  }
};
```

In the above, I also further hid the variable function call behind a wrapper so that an outside function doesn't need to pass the object as a parameter as well.

Comment: Seems to match definition 3 here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend

Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: It's the other way around. EngineObject must mark Callable as friend.

Comment: Ahh... Corrected.